# C# Marshal.PtrToStringUni does not return unicode values

Tags: c#, unicode, marshalling

I'm using C# Marshal.PtrToStringUni(IntPtr) to read data from Sql Server
It returns Latin characters but doesn't give Unicode character correctly. For Unicode character I see some garbage
I'm missing some conversion?

Comment: Please update your post to include your code

Answer (score 1):

ANSI encoding is not Unicode. Use [PtrToStringUni](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dyf0tzy4(v=vs.110).aspx) method instead.

Comment: Don't you mean `PtrToStringAnsi` instead? Latin encoded strings are 8bit, Unicode strings are 16bit. `PtrToStringAnsi` expects 8bit input, `PtrToStringUni` expects 16bit input. If the data is returned as 8bit, `PtrToStringAnsi` would be more appropriate.